# How to use a variable as an index to get a specific value out of a JSON array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I simply want to pinpoint a specific value out of a JSON array.

Sample of JSON array:

```
{
    "00002": {
        "Job Number": "00002",
        "Company": "Corporate",
        "Supervisor": "Great Person",
        "Date Input": "2016-01-07"
    },

    "00003": {
        "Job Number": "00003",
        "Company": "SmallGuy",
        "Supervisor": "Awful Person",
        "Date Input": "2012-03-05"
    }
}
```

This works in Javascript:

```
alert(javascript_array["00002"].Company);
```

But I want use a **dynamic variable** to call a record, like this:

```
var my_variable = 00002;

//OR I've tried:

var my_variable = "'"+00002+"'";

alert(javascript_array[my_variable].Company); //DOES NOT WORK. UNDEFINED??
```

No matter what I do, I can't use a variable mid-array call.

Help please!

Comment: What is `my_variable` ? Works here: https://jsfiddle.net/wsq3yj30/

Comment: Sorry, I just made an edit. Ideally, "my_variable" would be 00002, 00003, up to 99999 really...

Comment: Just do: `var my_variable = "00002"`, you are adding unneeded quotes (`"'00002'"`), which is why it can't find it.

Comment: Key variable must be a `String`, else, its `toString()` value will be used as key name.

Answer (score 2):

Use the string as key.

```
var my_variable = '00002';
```

```js
var object = { "00002": { "Job Number": "00002", "Company": "Corporate", "Supervisor": "Great Person", "Date Input": "2016-01-07" }, "00003": { "Job Number": "00003", "Company": "SmallGuy", "Supervisor": "Awful Person", "Date Input": "2012-03-05" } }
    my_variable = '00002';

document.write(object[my_variable].Company);
```

For getting all keys from the object, you can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
var object = { "00002": { "Job Number": "00002", "Company": "Corporate", "Supervisor": "Great Person", "Date Input": "2016-01-07" }, "00003": { "Job Number": "00003", "Company": "SmallGuy", "Supervisor": "Awful Person", "Date Input": "2012-03-05" } },
    keys = Object.keys(object);

keys.forEach(function (k) {
    document.write(object[k].Company + '<br>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your key is a string, but your variable isn't, so there's no match. Just use this:

```
var my_variable = "00002";
```

Answer (score 0):

To access key items for a JSON object you need to use strings, but if not it will attempt to convert the value into a string using `.toString()`. For your first case you are attempting to define a number:

```
var my_variable = 00002;
```

Although `00002` isn't a valid value for a number, as such it will contain the value `2`, and converted to a string it's `"2"`. In your JSON there is no such `javascript_array["2"]`. The second case has a similar problem:

```
"'"+00002+"'" => "'"+2+"'" => "'2'"
```

Also there is not such `javascript_array["'2'"]`, along with this you are adding unneeded quotes `'...'`. In this case (*as others pointed out*) just define `my_variable` as a string with the value `"00002"`.

```
var my_variable = "00002";
```